# Slow performance on splitting a shapefile by attributes

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I've tried to develop some workflows with the ArcPy module for splitting a shapefile based on the unique values in a specified field. The code works as expected except one thing I am not able to figure out.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

#getting user inputs
in_fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #'roads.shp'
outfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #r'C:\GIS\Temp\OutSHP'
fieldname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #"FEATURE"
createfolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #true/false
env.workspace = outfolder

#user chosen NOT to create a folder with the name of feature class
#
if createfolder == "false":

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_fc, ["{0}".format(fieldname)]) as cursor: #defining a search cursor
        for row in cursor:

            if not arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(outfolder,row[0])): #checking if shapefile already exists
                #Analysis toolbox > Extract > Select GP tool to select features
                arcpy.Select_analysis(in_fc, os.path.join(outfolder,row[0]), ''' "FEATURE" = '{0}' '''.format(row[0]))
            else:
                    print "The shapefile with this name already exists"


#user chosen to create a folder with the name of feature class
#
else:

   with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_fc, ["{0}".format(fieldname)]) as cursor: #defining a search cursor
        for row in cursor:
            directory = os.path.join(outfolder,row[0]) #create a path for directory that will be created
            if not os.path.exists(directory): #checking if directory exists
                os.makedirs(directory)

                if not arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(directory,row[0])): #checking if shapefile already exists
                #Analysis toolbox > Extract > Select GP tool to select features
                    arcpy.Select_analysis(in_fc, os.path.join(directory, row[0]), ''' "FEATURE" = '{0}' '''.format(row[0]))
                else:
                    print "The shapefile with this name already exists"
```

I've created a script tool in ArcGIS which takes an input shapefile, an output folder, a field name and whether user wants to create a folder for each unique value in the specified field before creating a shapefile there (the folder and the shapefile will have identical name except .shp in the end for shapefiles).

The issue is that the tool gets the work done for 5 seconds when user chooses to create folder with the unique name for each feature class and for around 3 *minutes* if the shapefiles are created directly in the output folder. I am having hard times trying to find out anything that could stipulate this behaviour in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare your script to this one...it should work in 10.1 although not tested.
http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=37AEB018-1422-2418-A036-CA6D9920F808

Comment: Thanks, Dan! Have already seen this one. Your script's logic is fairly different from mine - I'm only learning Python now and thus trying to build the code starting really simple :) do you have any idea why the tool works so slower that are applicable specifically to the code I posted? It feels as it does some unneccessary work yet I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Alex
to begin with directory should be made a variable since it doesn't have to use the os.path repeated calls  ie  arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(directory,row[0])):  it calls os.path, then does a join etc etc.  If something can be made a variable, then it doesn't need to be repeated.

Comment: Thanks, Dan. Good point, there is always room for improvement :). However, since the os.path.join is being performed in both scenarios (when the folders get created and not), I don't think it is this part that makes the code run 200 times slower when the folders do not get created. I believe it is some logical error that forces the script runs slower when writing shapefiles directly to the output without creating individual folders.